# SQL: how to get random number of rows from one table for each row in another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, random

I have two tables where the data is not related
For each row in table A i want e.g. 3 random rows in table B

This is fairly easy using a cursor, but it is awfully slow

So how can i express this in single statement to avoid RBAR ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a random number between 0 and (N-1), you can use.

```
abs(checksum(newid())) % N
```

Which means to get positive values 1-N, you use

```
1 + abs(checksum(newid())) % N
```

*Note: `RAND()` doesn't work - it is evaluated once per query batch and you get stuck with the same value for all rows of tableA.*

The query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableA A
  JOIN (select *, rn=row_number() over (order by newid())
          from tableB) B ON B.rn <= 1 + abs(checksum(newid())) % 9
```

*(assuming you wanted up to 9 random rows of B per A)*

Answer (score 0):

assuming tableB has integer surrogate key,  try

```
 Declare @maxRecs integer = 11 -- Maximum number of b records per a record
 Select a.*, b.*
 From tableA a Join tableB b
     On b.PKColumn % (floor(Rand() * @maxRecs)) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed number that you know in advance (such as 3), then:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a cross join
     (select top 3 * from b) b
```

If you want a random number of rows from "b" for each row in "a", the problem is a bit harder in SQL Server.

Comment: The second question should be `top 3 *` rather than `top 3`, but I can't edit the answer.

Comment: And there should be an `order by newid()` in the subquery.  Why do I keep getting errors when trying to post here?

Comment: Will this get three _different_ 'random' rows from `b` in `a`, or are the same three rows always going to be used (because of the inner `SELECT`...).  I have a feeling the OP may be going for 3 different rows each time.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Ask that question on meta (about problems connecting or posting)

Comment: @ypercube . . . Thank you for the suggestion, but the question has already been asked and it doesn't seem to have a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of how this could be done, code is self contained, copy and press F5 ;)

```
-- create two tables we can join 
DECLARE @datatable TABLE(ID INT)
DECLARE @randomtable TABLE(ID INT)

-- add some dummy data
DECLARE @i INT = 1
WHILE(@i < 3) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @datatable (ID) VALUES (@i)
    SET @i = @i + 1
END 

SET @i = 1
WHILE(@i < 100) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @randomtable (ID) VALUES (@i)
    SET @i = @i + 1
END 

--The key here being the ORDER BY newid() which makes sure that 
--the TOP 3 is different every time
SELECT 
    d.ID AS DataID
    ,rtable.ID RandomRow
FROM @datatable d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 3 * FROM @randomtable ORDER BY newid()) as rtable ON 1 = 1
```

Heres an example of the output

[image: randomrow]